# This 'for' loop prints '1' instead of an array value

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, codeblocks

Why does this...

```
int a[5];
a[-2] = 1;
a[-1] = 2;
a[0] = 3;
a[1] = 4;
a[2] = 5;

cout << a[-2] << endl <<endl;

for(int i=-2 ; i<=2 ; i++)
{
    cout << a[i] << endl;
}
```

...output this?

```
1

-2
2
3
4
5
```

I created another project file in [Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks), compiled, and got this:

```
1

1
-1
3
4
5
```

I tried to find posts with similar problems, but I couldn’t find any. This just doesn’t make sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing arrays in *C++* using negative indices is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), the valid index for:

```
int a[5];
```

will be `0 to 4`.

If we look at the draft C++ standard section `8.3.4` *Arrays* in paragraph *1* says:

> [...] If the value of the constant expression is N, the array has N elements numbered 0 to N-1, [...]

Answer (score 2):

Your code exhibits undefined behavior: `-2` is not a valid index into `int[5]` array. Valid indexes into such array are 0 through 4.

In this particular case, it just so happens, by accident, that `i` is located in memory at exactly the offset `2 * sizeof(int)` below the first element of `a`, so `a[-2]` happens to be an alias for `i`.